# Kong 2.8.0 alpine: drop of web socket connections

Tags: docker, websocket, kong

Good morning.

Recently we have adopted **Kong v.2.8.0 Alpine** as replacement for a very old version of Kong (both of them are docker images, taken from the repository via `docker pull`).

The issue: our application now - that is with Kong 2.8.0 - gives us an error that seems due to the drop of web socket connections, after exactly 60 seconds.

Obviously with the old Kong our application was running fine.

That said: is there a way to disable or - at least - increase the timeout?

Thanks,
A.R.

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved: it was a timeout configured in the settings of the load balancer that we have adopted in conjunction with Kong 2.8.0.